# Sharedpreference lost when force stopping activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm working on a step counter app and I want to save step data in sharedpreference but when I return to home page and restart the app the data just disappear 
and following is part of my code
How can I solve this problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String finalstep="";
    String valuestring1= null;

    private static final String step = "STEP";

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    int date = Integer.parseInt(strDate);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void readData(){
        settings = getSharedPreferences(step,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        textSteps.setText(settings.getString(valuestring1, ""));
    }

    public void resetSteps(View v) {
        String strDate1 = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        int date1 = Integer.parseInt(strDate1);
        if(date1==date) {
            readData();
            textSteps.setText(valuestring1);
        }
        else{
            date=date1;
            numSteps = 0;
            textSteps.setText(String.valueOf(numSteps));
        }
    }
    public void saveData(){
        String s = String.valueOf(finalstep);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(step,0);
        settings.edit()
                .putString(s, valuestring1).commit();
    }

    public void pressed (View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.exit) {
  saveData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't wanna improve the problem, would you, though? :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling the **clear()** SharedPreferences method or you are setting your SharedPreferences object to **null** in the onPause(), onStop() or onDestroy() method. Doing this will make you lose your data previously stored in the SharedPreferences object you created.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading and writing your shared preferences data with different keys:

> ```
> textSteps.setText(settings.getString(valuestring1, ""));
> ```

Here `valuestring1` is the key.

> ```
> settings.edit()
>             .putString(s, valuestring1).commit();
> ```

Here `s` is the key and `valuestring1` is the value.

You should be using the same key for writing and reading.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `readData();` in `onCreate()`metod and missed `}` at the end `onCreate()` method.